# How to add schema.org SiteNavigationElement and property URL to navbar?

Tags: menus, navigation

I would like to add the schema.org `SiteNavigationElement` and the relative url property to the links of the navbar.

I have the following:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="menu-nav" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
      'sort_column'     => 'menu_order',
      'theme_location'  => 'header-menu',
      'items_wrap'      => '<ul class="menu-nav navbar-nav scroll-menu">%3$s</ul>',
      'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse menu-header '
    ) ); ?>
  </nav>
```

I understand that `itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement"` should go to the `<nav>`. That's fine, and I can do that.

However how can I add
`itemprop="url"` to the links of that navbar??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little searching got me the `nav_menu_link_attributes` filter:

```
function wpse183311_filter( $atts, $item, $args ) {
    $atts['itemtype'] = 'http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement';
    return $atts;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_link_attributes', 'wpse183311_filter', 3, 10);
```

Add however many attributes you need to the `$atts` array as necessary

Comment: Hi, I think this is not what I need. Because I can add  `itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement"` directly in the code below editing just the HTML. The problem, as I wrote above, is to add `itemprop="url"` to every URL of the navbar. These are wordpress menu functions, and this code is not in the theme.

Comment: That's exactly what this code does.. If you look at the code it shows you the method for adding any attribute you want to the links in a nav menu..

Comment: This answer does assume a knowledge of basic PHP and basic WordPress filters, was I wrong in that assumption? Or were you looking for a lazy copy paste step by step instructions for non-developers

Comment: Well, I wanted the lazy version :) But I understood it and it works fine. Thanks.